# Should I cast a nullable double to an int?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

Hypothetically, I have two SQL tables: `Table` and `AuditTable`. In `Table` is a column, `org_id`, of type float with nulls allowed. Also, `org_id` is not a primary key. A column with the same name resides in `AuditTable`. I also have an `EditTable` class used to make changes to `Table` and `AuditTable`. The members of `EditTable` are set via a user interface. `EditTable` also contains a org_id member.

There is no good reason why `Table.org_id` was made a float; it will always contain an integer value. However, since `Table` was already existing, I can't change the type of `Table.org_id`. However, since I created `AuditTable` and `EditTable` I can set `AuditTable.org_id` and `EditTable.org_id` to any type.

When Visual Studio converts `Table` into a C# class, Table.org_id is made a `Nullable<double>`. Should I make `AuditTable.org_id` a float with nulls allowed and make `EditTable.org_id` a nullable double to match `Table.org_id`? Or should I make both `AuditTable.org_id` and `EditTable.org_id` ints and then do some casting? However, I was thinking about staying away from casting to be on the safe side and just make the types match the orginal `Table`.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You can change the type of an already-existing column.

Comment: Yes, but it would have bad effects on existing data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, it is a bad idea to store join keys as floating point numbers.  I wish that SQL actually banned this practice.  The issue is that 0.9999999999 might look like 1.00000000, but they don't match when joining (or in a `where` clause).  Much better to have what-you-see-is-what-you-get for such conditions.

First, go to whoever you can and beg/bribe/flatter/encourage them to do:

```
 alter table `table` modify org_id int;
```

If that doesn't work, you have a conundrum.  It is much better for query performance to have join keys be of the same types, even types that I don't agree with.  Also, that is a pretty important concept for databases.  So, you cannot change that join key.

Instead, I think you should add a new key into your table, called something like `org_id_int`.  This would have the correct type, a useful index -- everything except a pretty name.  Use this for your joins.  Use the other key for the joins to the existing table, until it gets fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately, Table.org_id is already in use by other systems and it would be difficult to change it to an int--I asked.

Comment: @navig8tr . . . I would actually consider this to be a bug in the system, that should be fixed at some point.

Comment: I agree. I'll try to raise the issue again

Comment: After adding org_id_int, would you then add/delete/modify its records at the same time as the org_id column?

Comment: @navig8tr . . . Yes, the two columns would need to be consistent.